# Time Complexity through recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion, fibonacci-numbers, homogeneous-equation

Suppose I have a code whose runtime complexity is described as a second degree linear homogeneous recursion formula as fn = fn−1 + fn−2, n>=3 where f1 = 1 and f2 = 2. I want to find constant c such that the runtime complexity of the algorithm can be described as Θ(c^n). I solved the recurrence relation but I don't understand how to compute it as Θ(c^n). Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

$$f_n=\frac{\text{Fibonacci}(n)+\text{Lucas}(n)}{2}$$
As $$\underset{n\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\;\frac{f_n}{\phi ^n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{10} $$
We can say that the $c$ you are looking for is the golden ratio
$$\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$

Comment: I was wondering why 'c' can't be (1-sqrt(5))/2

Comment: @aryaagg $f_n\le\left(\frac{\sqrt 5+5}{10}\right)\phi^n\to f_n= O(\phi^n)$. $\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)$ is negative, BTW

Comment: Will Θ(c^n)band O(c^n) here will yield the same value for c?

Comment: @aryaagg Θ(c^n) and O(c^n) are the same thing. Big O notation is almost everywhere in algorithm complexity theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity